# Ant combine two refid to use as a classpath

Tags: ant, junit

I have two refid to paths 'config.classpath' and 'test.classpath'.

Now I would like to write something like

```
<path id="config.classpath">
    <filelist dir="${lib.dir}">
        ...
    </filelist>
</path>

<path id="test.classpath">
    <filelist dir="${lib.dir}">
        <file name="junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
    </filelist>
</path>

<target name="test">
    <junit>
        <classpath>
            <filelist refid="test.classpath"/>
            <filelist refid="config.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        ...
    </junit>
</target>
```

When I run the test task the build fails with

```
test.classpath doesn't denote a filelist
```

So I removed the  part of the whole stuff and tried it like this

```
<filelist dir="${lib.dir}" id ="test.classpath">
    <file name="junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
</filelist>
```

But then it failed with

```
test.classpath doesn't denote a path
```

At that point I got a bit angry, since it was a path before and now that it isn't anymore it is complaining that it isn't one.

How can I combine those two path ( without writing 30 extra lines ) in the junit task.

I also tried this

```
<path id="test.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

But that gave me the "not a filelist error" too.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that your references are *paths* and not *filelists*. You need to use `<path>` in your classpath:

```
<target name="test">
    <junit>
        <classpath>
            <path refid="test.classpath"/>
            <path refid="config.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        ...
    </junit>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fileset instead of filelist and reference is as path in the classpath

```
<path id="config.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        ...
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="test.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="test">
    <junit>
        <classpath>
            <path refid="test.classpath"/>
            <path refid="config.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        ...
    </junit>
</target>
```

My local test example was the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project" default="default">
    <description>
            description
    </description>
    <property name="lib.dir" location="${basedir}/target/lib"></property>

    <path id="config.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="test.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="commons-io-2.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path> 
    <target name="default" description="description">


        <available classname="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils" property="string.utils.found" classpathref="config.classpath"></available>
        <available classname="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils" property="io.utils.found" classpathref="config.classpath"></available>

        <echo>string.utils.found=${string.utils.found}</echo>
        <echo>io.utils.found=${io.utils.found}</echo>

        <!-- combined classpath -->
        <available classname="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils" property="string2.utils.found">
            <classpath>
                    <path refid="test.classpath"></path>
                    <path refid="config.classpath"></path>
                </classpath>
        </available>
        <available classname="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils" property="io2.utils.found" >
            <classpath>
                    <path refid="test.classpath"></path>
                    <path refid="config.classpath"></path>
                </classpath>
        </available>

        <echo>string2.utils.found=${string2.utils.found}</echo>
        <echo>io2.utils.found=${io2.utils.found}</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Output:

```
     [echo] string.utils.found=true
     [echo] io.utils.found=${io.utils.found}
     [echo] string2.utils.found=true
     [echo] io2.utils.found=true
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: I wrote that I already tried that and threw the "not a filelist error" - last paragraph of my post

Comment: Please try again. maybe its a cache problem